# Redirect output window to log file

Tags: c#, .net

When my app starts, I see that following lines are written to the output window:

```
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Luna\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Luna.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\3.0.0.0_nl_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\3.5.1.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.resources\2.0.0.0_nl_b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.resources.dll'
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MyApp.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
```

I like to add these lines to my log file (and assign timestamp) for some performance measurements. I've tried to do that with the following class I created.

```
public static class ConsoleLogger
{
    public class LogWriter : TextWriter
    {
        public LogWriter()
        {
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }

        public override void Write(string value)
        {
            Logger.Info(value);                
        }
    }

    public static void RedirectConsoleLog()
    {
        Console.SetOut(new LogWriter());
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The Write() method is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: How/where are you using this custom `LogWriter` class?

Comment: @Subhash: Definitely Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are generated by the debugger.  The kind of notifications that can be generated by a debugger are documented in [this SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679308%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The DLL load notification corresponds with event 6, LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT.  The list pretty much corresponds with what you find back in the context menu when you right-click the Output window.  "Module Load Messages" for the ones you're interested in.

This has several implications.  First off, only a debugger can ever get these notifications, you normally run your program without one after it is deployed.  A hard restriction in Windows is that a debugger must be a separate process, a program cannot debug itself.  The last nail in your plan is that the IDE doesn't support redirecting what is now sent to the Output window into a file.

You can't make this work unless you write your own debugger.  Technically possible, download the [MDbg sample](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en).  Practically not.

Comment: @Robbert, unpalatable answers are usually the most frustrating ones to stomach, but sometimes they're the right ones. To get precisely what you're after this answer is just that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) or File->SaveoutputAs in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks, but I want to add these log to the already existing logfile of my application and include a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to this is to handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyLoad` event. The simplest example of this is:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationN
{
    class Program
    {
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);

            // You need to *DO* something here to trigger an assembly load
            // For example, open a database connection
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
        {
            // This is just an example of how to use what's provided in "args"
            Console.WriteLine(args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

This won't capture everything you're after, nor will it provide exactly the same format as the Visual Studio Output window but it *might* be an acceptable "half-way" house between that and nothing.